# In git can I merge one file onto a empty branch?

Tags: git, merge

Let's say I have a project that I have worked on for a while, 
then I would like to start over with a subset of the files and keep the history of those files.

So is there a way that I can manually merge one file onto the new empty branch?
Or do I need to merge over all the files and then remove the ones I don't want any more?

I was trying this workflow (but it don't really work)

```
$> git init 
$> vi file1.c
$> git add file1.c
$> git commit -m 'first commit'
$> vi file2.c
$> git add file2.c
$> git commit -m 'added file2'
$> git log 
commit 3788d18e62812d43f6b745f66fdab77081d79711
commit 3ab6959385c09fe2e254104a319a553ee58b198a

$> git checkout @{0}
Note: checking out '3ab6959385c09fe2e254104a319a553ee58b198a'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 3ab6959... first commit
$> git branch -a
* (no branch)
  master

$> git branch new_branch
$> git branch 
* (no branch)
  master
  new_branch

$> git checkout new_branch 
Switched to branch 'new_branch'

$> git mergetool master file1.c
merge tool candidates: opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse ecmerge p4merge araxis emerge vimdiff

master: file not found
Continue merging other unresolved paths (y/n) ? n
```

Why do I get "master: file not found"?

How should that merge look like?

Or how do I merge a specific file at a specific commit over to the new branch?

Comment: Hm, interesting question. I'm not sure if you are abusing git here a bit. It sounds like a new project instead of a new branch. Not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way that kind of does this

```
$> git checkout new_branch
$> git merge old_branch
$> git rm -rf *
$> git commit -m 'new try'
$> git checkout old_branch file1.c
$> git commit -a -m 'Fetch file1'
```

Then we have only file1 and kept file1:s history.

Answer (score 0):

You can try committing the file you want to migrate onto your old branch, switch to the new branch and cherry-pick the commit onto the new one. The instructions that follow assume you've already created two branches: oldBranch and newBranch.

On branch oldBranch, make modifications to the file you want to migrate over, then...

```
git add fileForOtherBranch.txt
git commit fileForOtherBranch.txt -m "I want to migrate this file to my other branch."

git status

(get the SHA number: will be a mess of 40 characters but you only need the first 7 or so, like ae09g4w)

git checkout newBranch
git cherry-pick ae09g4w
```

Note: the working directory in newBranch must be clean for this to work.

Comment: But cherry-pick does not work since I do not have 1 commit to pick, I have a file with multiple commits. And I cant modify the history of the other branch.